# why stat_compare_means(method = "anova") gives different pval than aov()

Tags: ggplot2, anova, p-value, ggpubr, significance

everyone I am trying to figure out how does stat_compare_means works

I tried to use stat_compare_means(method = "anova") in order to display pval on my boxplot. But then I ran also aov() on my data and I have completely different pvals. Any guess?